# another way to open the browser using the selenium module Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

how can I open the browser page without using chromedriver, for example, I want data to be saved in the main browser used by the user when executing the program, when data is not saved with the use of chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

I think might be wrong here but there is no way you can do that.
You might wanna use 'import webbrowser' as this will open up your default browser so everything will be saved in your main browser.
example

```
import webbrowser

google= 'www.google.com'
webbrowser.open(google)
```

i hope this helps

Comment: nothing helped because the following details were not entered in the appropriate field webdriver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")
webdriver.send_keys("text")

Answer (score 0):

Use profile,

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)